# Interface with optional type parameter

Tags: c#

Is it possible to haven an interface and the class that implements it have an optional type parameter?

Maybe this explains what i would like:

```
interface IModule<T = null> 
{
   T ExecuteModule();
}
```

So i would love both these classes to be use the interface

```
class ModuleOne : IModule<null>
{
    public void ExecuteModule(){
    // code returning nothing 

    };
}

class ModuleTwo : IModule<ReturnClass>
{
    public ReturnClass ExecuteModule(){
    // code returning ReturnClass

    };
}
```

I know that i can overload the interfaces and have two interfaces with the same name, one with and one without type parameter. The problem is that then they cant be used together for example in a List

Comment: This link has your answer https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131036/why-is-void-not-allowed-as-a-generic-type-in-c